# How to get last inserted date of a certain record using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Below I have a working code:

```
$p_code = "R-BIGANTE-010";
$date = date("m/d/Y");
$statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE p_code=? AND date=?");
$statement->execute(array($p_code, $date));
```

And what it does is to get a certain item with p_code and date equal to TODAY. What I want to know is how can I query a specific item with the last latest update?

For example, in my `items` table I have

[image]

As you can see, I have two `p_code` with value `"R-BIGANTE-010"`. Let's say the current date today is `05/06/2017` and I want to get the highlighted one because the `date` field is much latest than the other value.

How can I query it? By the way the date value is in `varchar` since the code is old and I will clean everything later.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's best to use dates in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), `YYYY-MM-DD`, for a multitude of reasons, but one of which is the native `DATE` column type accepts them without conversion. Other formats are often ambiguous: 01/02/2017 could be February 1st or January 2nd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date is in m/d/y format, you'll have to sort differently by converting the varchar dates to real dates using the [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function.

```
SELECT * from tablename 
WHERE p_code = ?
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y') DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

You should really use DATE data type for dates, not VARCHAR.

Comment: I will do sir. Your code works by the way. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the the last updated date by making a `select query with order by and limit` like:

```
SELECT * from tablename ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Your date is stored in varchar column, so try [STR_TO_DATE](http://%20%20You%20will%20want%20the%20STR_TO_DATE%20function%20%20SELECT%20columns%20FROM%20table%20ORDER%20BY%20STR_TO_DATE(varCharDateColumn,%20'%25m/%25d/%25Y%20%25h:%25i:%25s')) function

```
SELECT * from tablename
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s');
```

Comment: Would it work if my date field is in varchar? but the format is m/d/y

Comment: @FewFlyBy accept any one of the answer, which works for you. As it helps other community members.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from tablename  WHERE p_code=? ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Try this: 
     $p_code = "R-BIGANTE-010";
     $date = date("m/d/Y");
     $statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE p_code=? AND date=?");
     $statement->execute(array($p_code, $date));
     $id = $statement->lastInsertId();

If you want to do it with SQL instead of the PDO API query:

    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
    $lastId = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```